# WSO2 Is Single Sing ON with OpenId Connect

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, openid-connect

I need to implement SSO with openid connect in WSO2 IS 5.3.0.
All documentation, articles dealing with SSO are referred to SAML. 
I have read in the "Thirty Solution Patterns with the WSO2 Identity Server" that the solution is "In each service provider, configure WSO2 Identity Server as a trusted identity provider". 
How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide links.

Comment: Hi Bhathiya.I am asking about configuration, I have several webb apps, that autenticate against LDAP. ¿How I can configure SSO with  OpenId Connect?

Comment: I meant the links for what you have said you read.